# Spring generic converter issue with conversion of String

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am facing an issue while posting a select box data to spring controller.

```
<form:select path="ContactInfoVO[0].cityId" multiple="single" id="city" class="validate[required] small">       
    <form:option value="-1" label="-- Select City--"></form:option>                     
    <c:forEach var="city" items="${ManagerVO.ContactInfoVO[0].cityList}" varStatus="item">
    <form:option value="${city.cityId}" label="${city.cityName}"/>
</c:forEach> 
</form:select>
```

Spring's generic conversion service is adding ',' before the actual value. Looking into logs i saw following -

```
    23:00:45,511 DEBUG BeanWrapperImpl:579 - Using cached nested BeanWrapper for property 'restaurantContactInfoVO[0]'
23:00:45,512 DEBUG GenericConversionService:139 - Checking if I can convert java.lang.String[] to java.lang.String
23:00:45,516 DEBUG GenericConversionService:358 - Searching for converters indexed by sourceType [[Ljava.lang.String;]
23:00:45,517 DEBUG GenericConversionService:429 - and indexed by targetType [java.lang.String]
23:00:45,519 DEBUG GenericConversionService:429 - and indexed by targetType [java.io.Serializable]
23:00:45,520 DEBUG GenericConversionService:429 - and indexed by targetType [java.lang.Comparable]
23:00:45,521 DEBUG GenericConversionService:429 - and indexed by targetType [java.lang.CharSequence]
23:00:45,523 DEBUG GenericConversionService:429 - and indexed by targetType [java.lang.Object]
23:00:45,524 DEBUG GenericConversionService:358 - Searching for converters indexed by sourceType [[Ljava.lang.Object;]
23:00:45,527 DEBUG GenericConversionService:429 - and indexed by targetType [java.lang.String]
23:00:45,528 DEBUG GenericConversionService:473 - Found matchable converters org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToStringConverter@ba3bff5
23:00:45,530 DEBUG GenericConversionService:560 - Matching org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToStringConverter@ba3bff5
23:00:45,531 DEBUG GenericConversionService:139 - Checking if I can convert java.lang.String to java.lang.String
23:00:45,532 DEBUG GenericConversionService:246 - Matched cached converter org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@6f69b66e
23:00:45,534 DEBUG GenericConversionService:147 - Yes, I can convert
23:00:45,535 DEBUG GenericConversionService:564 - Matched converter org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToStringConverter@ba3bff5
23:00:45,536 DEBUG GenericConversionService:254 - Caching under ConverterCacheKey [sourceType = java.lang.String[], targetType = java.lang.String]
23:00:45,537 DEBUG GenericConversionService:147 - Yes, I can convert
23:00:45,539 DEBUG GenericConversionService:159 - Converting value array<String>['', '145009'] of java.lang.String[] to java.lang.String
23:00:45,542 DEBUG GenericConversionService:246 - Matched cached converter org.springframework.core.convert.support.ArrayToStringConverter@ba3bff5
23:00:45,544 DEBUG GenericConversionService:159 - Converting value '' of java.lang.String to java.lang.String
23:00:45,545 DEBUG GenericConversionService:246 - Matched cached converter org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@6f69b66e
23:00:45,546 DEBUG GenericConversionService:186 - Converted to ''
23:00:45,548 DEBUG GenericConversionService:159 - Converting value '145009' of java.lang.String to java.lang.String
23:00:45,551 DEBUG GenericConversionService:246 - Matched cached converter org.springframework.core.convert.support.ObjectToStringConverter@6f69b66e
23:00:45,552 DEBUG GenericConversionService:186 - Converted to '145009'
23:00:45,554 DEBUG GenericConversionService:186 - Converted to ',145009'
```

i have one more select box and code for both are identical(almost). Still i do not know why spring treat this one as String[] and not String. Can someone put some light on this?

Comment: If you look at the raw request params when your controller is triggered you'll probably see that there are two instances of that param (in question). One will have the value 145009 and the other will be empty. That is why you are seeing a `String[]` instead of `String`. You need to work out why that param is being set twice. Is there a hidden field with the same `name` or a second input in that form with the same `name`? Look at the HTML source not your JSP to check this.

Comment: yes, just noticed same param was used in a hidden text box which was not populating. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was another parameter on the form with same id causing this issue. It is now fixed.